# Fadein(), set 'display: table' instead of block

Tags: jquery

Right now when I fade in my overlay div, it is automatically set to `display: block;`. But I want it to be `display: table`. Is there any jQuery function like `fadein()` that does that?

**jQuery**

```
$.when($("#overlay").fadeIn(200)).done(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //ToDo
    });
}, 250);
```

Comment: just use `$("#overlay").css('display','table');`

Comment: There are issues with animations on table elements due to their layout.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$("#overlay").fadeIn(200).css('display','table');
```

Change the CSS property after the `fadeIn`.

Comment: This way, don't you lose the fadeIn effect pretty much?

Comment: In IE edge this causes a flicker effect which makes this route unusable for that browser.

Answer (score 3):

Set your `opacity: 0;` in CSS or inline in the HTML then run this.  You can have `display: table;` already set before it runs.

If you need `display: none;` to be default (to remove the space taken in the DOM, etc), follow this below:

```
$('#overlay').animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, {duration: 200, start: function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'table');
    }
});
```

If you don't need `display: none;`, just take the `start()` function out.

Comment: is `opacity:0` = `display:none;` ?

Comment: no, you can do both if needed though.  If you put `display: none` just edit the animate to set the display to table at the start.  I'll edit the answer so you can see it

Comment: There. `fadeIn` is already doing that. It unhides the element first. Wouldn't setting the css after fadeIn be a lot simpler.

Comment: @abhitalks most certainly I actually did this on purpose because going from `display: block` to `display: table` on some browsers might have unexpected side effects (flicker/flash on IE possibly).  But essentially they're the same thing.  Here's the demo (that's not needed anymore lol) http://jsfiddle.net/tF3a4/2/

Comment: Fair enough :) plussing for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Working with your code:

```
$.when($("#overlay").fadeIn(200).css("display", "table")).done(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //ToDo
    });
}, 250);
```

Comment: this setTimeout is useless.. :)

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet And it is clearly commented `todo` by the OP... so perhaps it won't be useless for long :)